# HTTP/2 header compression

Tags: header, compression, http2

I am sending 4-5 consecutive HTTP/2 requests from a single client and the HTTP header is same for all the requests (and payload too).

The original header size is ~343 bytes. 
Client - Firefox, 
Server - Jetty

Then I measure the header size through wireshark. I can observe the header sizes of each request as below.

```
1st - 261 bytes
2nd -  55 bytes
3rd -  52 bytes
4th -  52 bytes
```

I assume first reduction of header size is due to sending indexes correspond to static headers and also due to literal encoding. After the first request, dynamic tables are populated and all the headers in the second request will be index values. Hence further reduction in the second request.

But I can't figure out why is there a reduction from 2nd request to 3rd request. I tested this with few original sizes of headers and same behavior is seen where there are 3 bytes reduction from 2nd request to 3rd request and then size become consistent.

Appreciate if anyone can assist with providing an explanation to this.

Comment: You can only know for sure by looking to the binary representation of the compressed headers. One possible cause however is the use of a [dynamic table update](https://http2.github.io/http2-spec/compression.html#encoding.context.update) right at the beginning of the second header.

Comment: HTTP/2 compressed "headers" also contain the HTTP method, the URI, the authority, etc. Are you sure that *everything* is exactly equal ?

Comment: I think that you have *a little different* requests, which will be compressed in another way. I don't think that you should seriously analyse the difference between tow requests with 52 and 55 bytes. If you do want to find the reason then you should post **full content** of the wireshark data. One can find the reason of the difference only analyzing of the exact data.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the HEADER frames, found out that it is the **dynamic header table size** update signal. Here, after the first request, encoder has decided to choose less capacity than max table size and signals that to the decoder in the second request.